# Direcionar todo o tráfego da raiz para sub pasta resulta em erro "403 forbidden" se não tiver "index.php"

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status, http-status-code-403

O código em baixo funciona perfeitamente para direcionar todo o tráfego do site de forma transparente para dentro da pasta `www`:

```
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Verificar o destino
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

# Ignorar se estamos a apontar para a pasta do projeto
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/

# Ignorar se estamos a apontar para um ficheiro ou diretoria existente
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Direcionar tudo para a sub-pasta "www"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L] [R=301,L]
```

O problema está no acesso direto via `ww.example.com` que apesar de servir a página em condições, resulta num *HTTP Status code* `403 forbidden` o que causa a falha de alguns serviços, entre os quais as partilhas sociais.

No entanto, se acedermos via `ww.example.com/index.php` o *HTTP status code* vem corretamente identificado como `200 OK`.

## Pergunta

Como resolver o problema dos acessos a `www.example.com` de forma a que continuem a direcionar o tráfego, mas resultem num *HTTP status code* `200 OK` ?

---

**Nota:** A navegação no web-site é realizada com URLs simplificados tipo:

```
www.example.com/produtos/bananas/banana-da-madeira
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `Options +FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: Ou colocar `RewriteRule ^(.*)[\\|\/]$ /www/$1/index.php [L] [R=301,L]` antes do seu `RewriteRule`, acho que ele não está identificando o documento padrão na pasta destino.

Answer (score 1):

Ao usar a `flag` (sinalizador) `R=301` o `rewrite` força o redirecionamento, ao que entendi você não quer redirecionar, mas apenas reescrever a URL, se for o caso, você **não** deve usar está `flag`, basta usar:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

Suponho que a pasta `www` seja uma pasta criar por ti e não a pasta de uso do apache, por exemplo, se fosse um sistema linux sua pasta seria algo como `/var/etc/www/www`, se for isto então o seu código me parece correto, com exceção do sinalizador `R`.

No caso eu sempre uso o sinalizador `QSA` junto ao `L`, para acaso queira passar parâmetro `GET` junto (por exemplo se vier de um anuncio do Google `/?gclid=...`), ficaria algo como:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Detalhes: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Answer (score 0):

Acredito já ter tentado, mas você já colocou desta forma:

```
# Direcionar tudo para a sub-pasta "www"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/index.php$1 [L] [R=301,L]
```